# Loopback.js after save is not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

So I have the following code:

```
loopbackModels.findModel("academy_automatic_event").find({
  where: {
    automatic_event_type: 1,
    active: true
  },
  include: {
    academy: ['versions']
  }
}).then(function(result) {
  let academyCreateArray = [];
  if (result && result.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      academyCreateArray.push({
        member_id: userInstance.id,
        academy_id: result[i].academy_id,
        academy_version_id: result[i].__data.academy.__data.versions[result[i].__data.academy.__data.versions.length - 1].academy_version_id
      })
    }    loopbackModels.findModel("member_has_academy").create(academyCreateArray).then(function(result) {
      next();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Now the important thing to take away from this is that I create new instances in the model `member_has_academy`.

So in that `.js` I have the following piece of code:

```
Memberhasacademy.afterRemote('after save', function(context, memberAcademyInstance, next) {
  loopbackModels.findModel("academy_activity").find({
    where: {
      academy_id: memberAcademyInstance.academy_id,
      academy_version_id: memberAcademyInstance.academy_version_id
    },
    order: 'sort_number ASC'
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result != null && result.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        loopbackModels.findModel("member_has_academy_activity").create({
          academy_activity_id: result[i].id,
          member_id: memberAcademyInstance.member_id,
          is_complete: false,
          taken: false,
          sort_number: result[i].sort_number,
          is_open: result[i].sort_number === 1
        })
      }
    }
    next();
  });
});
```

However, the hook is never called. Please note, I have also tried with `after create` but with the same result.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some digging i actually found the answer:

what i had to use was:

```
    Memberhasacademy.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
```